# Why does my C++ program close so slowly in debug mode on Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

Is this normal? It might take 30 seconds or more to close it, but I can force close it by going to Debug -> Terminate all, and it closes instantly.

The only thing I can think of slowing down is a 2d vector, which usually is only size of  200000x1. So maybe it is somehow checking the memory before freeing it?

When I open my program directly from the exe, it loads and closes instantly.

Could there be a hidden bug in my program that causes this kind of slow closing behaviour?

Comment: If you look at the `Output` window, you will note it is telling you things like dll's it is unloading and memory leaks it is dumping.

Comment: It is checking the memory for leaks and some detection for corruption.

Comment: Looks like there are no errors. Perhaps make that as an answer if this actually is the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

debug mode provides features that can slow down the program